# Какой знак препинания ставится после слова "принцип"?

Tags: пунктуация

«И тут пищевые корпорации применяют древний принцип "не можешь победить — возглавь"».

Comment: В оригинале этот "древний принцип" формулируется "то, что нельзя запретить, нужно возглавить"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двоеточие. И если в кавычках, то с прописной, а если без, то со строчной.